# How to convert or parse Olson timestamp?

Tags: google-sheets

How do you convert `2016-03-05T08:30:00` to time in Google Spreadsheets?

I would like to convert it to "hh:mm:ss".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Assuming that the value is in `A1`. Use

```
=TIMEVALUE(Right(A1,8))
```

then apply the desired time format to the cell.

## Explanation

Google Sheets handles date, time and duration data as serial numbers. In several cases, this makes easy to do certain calculations that involves this kind of data. In some circumstances, functions like `TIMEVALUE` could display a number instead of a time in the desired format but this could be solved by applying the desired format.

[image: Time in hh:mm:ss]

To apply `hh:mm:ss` as the number format, click on Formats or the [image: 123 dropdown] button o the Google Sheets toolbar, then click on the following path:

Number > More formats > More date and time formats

A dialog like the following will be displayed:

[image: Custom date and time formats]

Click on the drop-down button to select a handler. Then click on the up/down arrows to select the desired format.

Comment: You also need to format the text as _hh:mm:ss_ or format it like so:  `=TEXT(TIMEVALUE(Right(A1,8)),"hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: That could be done as an alternative to the answer but is not "needed". I added an explanation :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and explanation. Above and beyond.

Comment: The OP does ask for a specific format: _hh:mm:ss_